# What is the history behind the term Modal in Angular/Web Development?

Tags: angular

I understand Modal is a webpage element that opens up separately from the main page so as to not disturb the flow. Is my understanding right?

I am trying to understand why it is called a Modal.

Is it short for modularity? As in, different Modals come together to make a page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a modal/modeless dialog called modal/modeless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607783/why-is-a-modal-modeless-dialog-called-modal-modeless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Modal" because it introduces a mode, as opposed to "modeless" which does not introduce a mode.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/modal-and-modeless-dialog-boxes?view=msvc-170):

> *Modal* dialog boxes, which require the user to respond before continuing the program
>
> *Modeless* dialog boxes, which stay on the screen and are available for use at any time but permit other user activities

Other links:

- [Why is a modal/modeless dialog called modal/modeless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607783/why-is-a-modal-modeless-dialog-called-modal-modeless)
- [What is a Modal Dialog Window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window)
- [Etymology of "modal dialogs" in computerese](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103192/etymology-of-modal-dialogs-in-computerese)